# Export model to collada outputs black

Tags: export, import, collada

I have imported the model on this webpage: http://pnn32.deviantart.com/art/Mirror-Disco-Ball-free-3D-model-blend-obj-399179670. And it looks like this:

[image: Imported disco ball]

I simply want to export the model as it is to collada format to import into xcode. When i export it comes out all black as such:

[image: Disco ball export]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try importing the exported mesh in blender again? Like is it appearing black in blender or xcode?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means? It appears black in xcode, like the second picture. The first picture is blender and looks ok

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Answer (score 0):

I had an experience where I imported an FBX model into Blender and it had a negative scaling factor applied to all axes of the model. I did an "Object>Apply>All transforms to deltas" and I thought that fixed it but it when I exported to Collada I got black textures like you describe.

To fix it I had to change all the scales to negatives again and then applied the transforms again. This resulted in an upside down model, so I rotated it to the correct angle to fix the orientation, then exported to Collada again and the textures displayed properly.

I hope this saves someone some effort!

Answer (score 0):

Might have to do with the alpha channel on the shading/material. I was having this issue and turning the alpha between 1 and 0 solved this.